# Why do I need to use .live() in Drupal Behaviors?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to be a good boy and use Drupal Behaviors to manage my JavaScript. My understanding is that one of the advantages of using Behaviors is that it frees you from having to use .live() to bind event handlers to dynamically created elements. However, I find that I have to use .live() all the time. What am I doing wrong?

Here is a simple example of what I'm talking about:

```
Drupal.behaviors.MySearch = {

  attach: function (context, settings) {

    var searchBox = $('#my-search-box');
    searchBox.append("<input type='text'></input>");
    searchBox.append("<button>Search</button>");

    $('#my-search-box button').click(function(){
      console.log("This does not work.");
    });

    $('#my-search-box button').live('click', function(){
      console.log("This does work.");
    });

};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My understanding is that one of the advantages of using Behaviors is that it frees you from having to use .live() to bind event handlers to dynamically created elements.

Yes and no. It certainly can be used for that, but it will only work if *Drupal* has invoked the previous AJAX call. If you've just done a `$.ajax(...)`, Drupal won't know about it, and `attachBehaviors()` won't be invoked.

I would guess that your `attach()` method is indeed only being invoked once, as it would explain perfectly why the click handler is assigned once (when the page is first loaded), but not again. The `live()` will always work no matter how many times your `attach()` method is called.

If that is the problem, to fix simply add this to your AJAX success callback:

```
Drupal.attachBehaviors();
```

Comment: Aside, [As of jQuery 1.7 `live()` is deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/).  Use `on()` instead.  Any comment?

Comment: @cdmo Only that Drupal 7 still ships with jQuery 1.4 by default...

Comment: Ah, right.  I override with a later version, thanks.

Comment: I think it's safe to say most people do these days @cdmo. You're right of course, jQuery Update + using `on()` would always be preferrable

Answer (score 0):

live() is always the best option because it dynamically bind ajax response but click doesn't. So always use live() or on() function

Comment: _Your version of jQuery might doesn't support click_ Which version of jQuery doesn't support `click()`? Considering it was added in 1.0, and is still there, you'd have to be using a pre-beta version from about 10 years ago for that to be true

Comment: Shabir -- I did verify that click() is supported; I will follow your advice of using live().

Comment: Sorry, guys! I used click in one of my application and it wasn't working I think it had an issue with drupal behaviour function - thanks for the correction @Clive